# How to access object property using string variable?

Tags: javascript, object

If I have an object like below:

```
this.state = {
  like: {
    count: 100,
    clicked: false
  },
  dislike: {
    count: 25,
    clicked: false
  }
};
```

If have a variable name of `var prop = 'like'`, how can I get the value of `this.state.like` using `prop` value?

I tried named property `[this.state.prop]` but it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bracket notation:

```
var prop = 'like';

var like = this.state[prop];
```